# angular2-select is not filling with the dynamic data

Tags: angular, angular2-select

I have an add group module on which there is user list for which I am using [angular2-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-select#getting-started) for multiple selections. The add group page open on click of a button. Here is the code

```
<ng-select [options]="users" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="group.selectedUsers" placeholder="select users" name="users"></ng-select>
```

And I am filling with this API response data

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.getAllUsers()
       .subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                this.users.push({ value: element.id, label: element.firstName});
            });
        })
}
```

Now the first time I open the add group page the user list is empty. The user list is filled after I open it the second time. Am I missing something?

Comment: how much data is actually there in the list?

Comment: 6 users for the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that your `this.users` remains the same object, so angular will not detect a change if you push items to it. Therefore the component will not be updated and your options will not show up.

To get this to work you should let `this.users` point to a new `Array`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe((data) => {
        this.users = data.map((element) => {
            return {
                value: element.id,
                label: element.firstName
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: now this is happening with some other variable.

let selectedUserIds =this.group.memberList.nameId.map((member: any) => { return member.id });
            this.selectedUsers = selectedUserIds;

can you solve this?

Comment: @SunilGarg What is happening exactly? This seems to be about setting the value instead of the options. In that case make sure that selectedUsers is a list of strings (Array<string>).